# Stop-Service Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've currently a simple scripts which is:

```
Stop-Service $ServiceName -Force
```

It does stop the service but in about 1/4 times it keeps the files locked so I still can't update them.

Is this some bug in Powershell? Am I missing something?

Comment: Which service? Which files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe drop the `-force` param unless a regular stop fails. You can also try the following loop:

```
Stop-Service $ServiceName
While ((Get-Service $ServiceName).Status -ne "Stopped") {
    Write-Host "Waiting for service to stop..."
    Sleep 5
}
```

This will let you know if it is taking longer than expected for the service to reach a fully `Stopped` state.

Answer (score 0):

Find out which process actually locks the files. Use a tool like `handle`, `procmon` or `procexp` from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx) toolkit.

Comment: I'm going to check this out!